# VS 2010 - set default scale for text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to set default scale for c# text editor in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use VSCommands Lite extension (free) from [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf)

[image]

Comment: you can disable it from extension manager or delete it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions. Is it causing you any problems?

Comment: it would be great if you could provide more details about performance hit (is it in code editor? c# ? xml? or overall performance?) I'm always looking for feedback, so let me know at support@vscommands.com or vscommands.com/community. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Performance really suck. Every operation that was instant before, now requires 2-3 seconds to complete: menu browsing, file opening. After uninstall everything back to normal. The version I've tried was the latest at the moment - 3.7.3.0.